# tanh function values are either 1 or -1, how to interpret that distribution

Tags: neural-networks

I have a question regarding the tanh function. I trained an NN (with tanh activation functions in hidden layers) on a multiclass dataset and visualised the tanh values of the complete samples from the dataset passed through the NN.

The question is why I only have the -1 and 1 values? What does it mean can we conclude something from that?[image]

thank a lot

Comment: Did you calculate activation in train data?

Comment: If this is a histogram of the pooled outputs of the hidden units of the network, it probably means that the model is overfitting (or that the classification problem is easily separable with no overlap in the distribution between classes)

Comment: @Firebug, yes these values are gathered outputs during the training of 5-th epoch